# How do you enumerate all accelerators in C++ AMP?

Tags: c++, c++-amp

In C++ AMP, how does one detect and enumerate all C++ AMP accelerators?

Don McCrady distributed an app [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2011/09/22/can-i-run-c-amp-on-my-device.aspx) that enumerates *non-emulated* accelerators. Though I had a DX11 card (GTX 260), I didn't see any available accelerators. Daniel Moth shows [here](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/concurrencyaccelerator.aspx) how to query an individual accelerator, but I couldn't find how do enumerate all (emulated and non) accelerators using a C++ AMP call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it's pretty simple: `concurrency::get_accelerators();` Daniel Moth [comments](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/CommentView,guid,c99a2ff4-0378-4e05-814d-c42ac646bd39.aspx#commentstart):

> in the VS 11 Developer Preview bits, you simply call concurrency::get_accelerators();. We are working to make that more discoverable for the Beta, whenever that is.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "amp.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace concurrency;

void inspect_accelerators()
{
    auto accelerators = accelerator::get_all();
    for_each(begin(accelerators), end(accelerators),[=](accelerator acc){ 
        wcout << "New accelerator: " << acc.description << endl;
        wcout << "is_debug = " << acc.is_debug << endl;
        wcout << "is_emulated = " << acc.is_emulated <<endl;
        wcout << "dedicated_memory = " << acc.dedicated_memory << endl;
        wcout << "device_path = " << acc.device_path << endl;
        wcout << "has_display = " << acc.has_display << endl;                
        wcout << "version = " << (acc.version >> 16) << '.' << (acc.version & 0xFFFF) << endl;
    });
}
```

**Update 1:**

As of VS 11 Beta, this is now accelerator::get_all();

Comment: Ah, just found the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh350903(v=VS.110).aspx

Comment: Here is the location of the new docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh350895(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reposting the answer from my blog here :-)

You made a side comment in your question:

"Though I had a DX11 card (GTX 260), I didn't see any available accelerators"

If Don's utility didn't find your card, then it is not a DX11 card, or there is a bug in his utility and we'd appreciate you reporting the repro to him. However, I verified on the vendor's site that GTX 260 is a DX10 card. So that would not be a good target for C++ AMP code, unfortunately...

Cheers

Daniel

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. You're absolutely right - not sure why dxdiag.exe on Win7 x86 was showing DX11. Went out and bought a GTX 560 Ti yesterday, and it's recognized correctly by Don's utility.